# Combining Semaphore to limit async requests and dispatch groups for .notify with defer and App is freezing

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a backend that can handle maximum 4 simultaneous network connections.  To compensate, I have made an array called `urlsQueue` that contains all the parameters needed for each network request.  The code below produces the results I want if the `urlsQueue` contains 4 or less elements.  However, if I enter `func downloadBusiness` with 5+ elements inside `urlsQueue`, the app freezes.

```
func downloadBusinesses(latitude: Double, longitude: Double){
    if urlsQueue.isEmpty {return}
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 4)
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for (index, element) in urlsQueue.enumerated(){
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        semaphore.wait()
        _ = Client.getBusinesses(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, offset: element.offset ,completion: { [weak self] (yelpDataStruct, result) in
            defer {
                semaphore.signal()
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
            self?.handleGetNearbyBusinesses(inputData: yelpDataStruct, result: result)
        })
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {[weak self] in
        self?.runDownloadAgain()
    }
}
```

If a network request succeeds, I remove the corresponding value from `urlsQueue`. If the network request fails, the entry stays inside `urlsQueue`.  After iterating through every element in `urlsQueue`, I repeat the process again if the loop is not empty.  That way I can re-do any failed network requests.

```
func runDownloadAgain(){
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { [weak self] timer in
        self?.downloadBusinesses(latitiude: self!.latitude, longitude: self!.longitude)
    }
    timer.fire()
}
```

I have been able to debug the breaking point in the app is within the for-enumerated loop above.  After the 4th time in the loop, everything just stops.  If I'm stepping through the program, I am unable to move forward.  If I adjust the hard-coded value of 4 to any other integer, the problem repeats with the code block only succeeding if `urlsQueue.count`  <= x where x is the value in `DispatchSemaphore(value: x)`

The problem lies in my improper mixing of dispatchGroup/semaphore/defer.  But I'm really struggling to see how I can re-combine these elements successfully to avoid the app freeze while limiting network connections to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you start always at index zero of the URL queue exit the loop if the index > 3 and drop the semaphore

```
func downloadBusinesses(latitiude: Double, longitude: Double){
    if urlsQueue.isEmpty {return}
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for (index, element) in urlsQueue.enumerated(){
        if index > 3 { break }
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        _ = Client.getBusinesses(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, offset: element.offset ,completion: { [weak self] (yelpDataStruct, result) in
            defer {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
            self?.handleGetNearbyBusinesses(inputData: yelpDataStruct, result: result)
        })
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { // GCD closures don't cause retain cycles
        self.runDownloadAgain()
    }
}
```

Comment: On your comment saying "GCD closures don't cause retain cycles", it doesn't create a cycle because you're not retaining the DispatchGroup and the closure is released once it's processed. If you don't call `leave` properly then it will be retained.